# Get the path or url of open directories/browsers in Ubuntu or Python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, operating-system

I want to get the path of all opened directories and urls opened in browser tabs through Ubuntu terminal or Python script. Also store those paths in a file.

Is there any way to do it?

I searched but didn't get any result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/338294/output-url-of-open-firefox-tabs-in-terminal

[How can I get list of open tabs in Firefox via a command-line application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674633/how-can-i-get-list-of-open-tabs-in-firefox-via-a-command-line-application)

https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/save-your-current-firefox-tabs-and-restore-them-later/

Comment: This should be a comment. It's no definite answer and simply providing links doesn't count as answering anyway.